# Redux shorthand `mapDispatchToProps` returns undefined for `async` actions / thunks

Tags: reactjs, redux, async-await, redux-thunk

I have encountered what I think might be a bug but could be my understanding.

Basically an `import` of an `async` `action` returns undefined inside a `Redux` container, but I know the import is fine (file exists, it's the right case etc etc).

On closer inspection, the issue seems to have started when I migrated to the shorthand object notation in my container, here's an example:

**thunks.js**

```
import { anAsyncFunc } from './anotherFile'
export const aThunk = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    await dispatch(anAsyncFunc)
    return dispatch(someOtherAsyncFunc)
}
```

**containerThatDoesntWork.js**

```
import { aThunk  } from './thunks.js'
import MyComponent from './MyComponent'

console.log(aThunk) // undefined

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    aThunk
}
```

**containerThatDoesWork.js**

```
import { aThunk  } from './thunks.js'
import MyComponent from './MyComponent'

console.log(aThunk) // undefined

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    aThunk: () => {
       console.log(aThunk) // return async function (dispatch, getState) { ... }
       return dispatch(aThunk())
    }
})
```

In both instances if I `console.log(aThunk)` in the `container` I get undefined which I presume is something to do with the module resolution of `async` functions?

However in the second example where the import is wrapped explicitly in a function, the component is happy and in the shorthand notation it is not (PropTypes validation fails).

Does anyone know a way round this? or is it a limitation to `mapDispatchToProps` in object shorthand notation?

Comment: Does it work if you rewrite your async action without `async`? Also, can you validate that `import { aThunk  }` actually imports something?

Comment: I'm unable to re-write that specific action to avoid `async` do to what it does, but other non `async` actions in the same component are bound OK. I'm confident the import returns something as it's oddly working in other files.
This could well be something to do with `import` resolution, but I'm at a loss as to why. As I say, the only way I can resolve this is to wrap the `action` in a function which calls dispatch explicitly.

Comment: When something unexpected happens, it means by definition that your expectations are wrong somewhere. So just for debugging purposes, I've suggested you to try to localize the problem. If `aThunk` is `undefined` when you provide it to `mapDispatchToProps`, it will be much easier to find the problem. If you can try to remove `async` from your action just for debugging, it'll also make the problem much more specific.

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer. Two answers, 1) If I remove async from the action just for debugging, it still doesn't work. 2) If I `console.log()` the function before the `mapDispatchToProps` it's undefined. However this is still the case in the **working** container version (wrapped in a function) but at the point it's passed to the component it's no longer defined. 
I presume this is because the import eventually resolves? and when wrapped in a function, the function points to the variable, rather than using the value of the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
    aThunk
}
```

and

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    aThunk: () => dispatch(aThunk())
})
```

are supposed to behave the same way. In case `mapDispatchToProps` is an object, properties are transformed to `() => dispatch(action)` automatically. Both should result in `aThunk` prop that returns the result of `aThunk()(dispatch)`, i.e. a promise.

Here is [a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mgaywq).

The only reason why named import can be undefined in module scope but exist in function scope is that there is circular dependency that was resolved at the time when a dependency was lazily accessed. Wrapping a dependency with a function like this was done with `dispatch => ...` is a known workaround around circular dependencies that is luckily supported by `mapDispatchToProps`, but it's preferable to not have them in the first place, especially if this isn't by design.

Comment: Interesting answer, I was under the impression the were the same, based on the docs here: https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-an-object This cites providing an object as an alternative "connect supports an “object shorthand” form for the mapDispatchToProps argument: if you pass an object full of action creators instead of a function, connect will automatically call bindActionCreators for you internally." am I missing something there?

Comment: I fixed the typo that was just a typo SO side, i'm not able to post the original code unfortunately

Comment: I initially misread `{
    aThunk
}` as `dispatch => {
    aThunk
}`. Otherwise I see no problems, it should work, I provided a demo. It's unclear where *I console.log(aThunk) in the container I get undefined* took place. Did you try to log outside `dispatch => ...` and inside of it to see the difference? This isn't related to async in any way, async is just syntactic sugar for promises. This could happen if you have circular dependencies. In the question they aren't shown.

Comment: I did consider circular references as that's what googling throws up and would explain why I don't see the problem with other actions in the project written in the same way. I have tried the circular dependency plugin and it doesn't show anything though which is a bit odd.

Comment: In case there's CD, it should be detectable by sight. Modules depend on each other in a way this prevents module import from being available right after `import`. Could be because of someOtherAsyncFunc or anything else you didn't show in the question. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for the problem . Again, *Did you try to log outside dispatch => ... and inside of it to see the difference?*

Comment: Yeah I'm currently trying to draw the dependency graph but to put it into context, there are 70 lines of imports in the `thunks` file (albeit most of them app constants) but it's quite complex to reason with.
I've updated the question to show the `console.log` as various points, as you can see the function is OK at a later point (the action is only called within the component after a form submission) so it's a much later point in the application execution. The initial import happens during app start up.

Comment: This clearly indicates CD. What you have with `dispatch => ... ` is a legit workaround, but I'd suggest to get rid of CD because it indicates that there's a flaw in dependency graph that wasn't expected. I updated the answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm starting to feel that way, what I'm now confused about is that I'd have expected webpack or babel to throw an error, or alternatively for the import to never resolve. I even tried getting https://www.npmjs.com/package/circular-dependency-plugin installed but it threw up nothing

Comment: It isn't Babel's duty to process modules, and Webpack shouldn't throw because CD are natural for ES modules. I cannot say why the plugin doesn't throw though. If you'll be able to replicate the problem (you don't really need Redux or React, console.log is enough), consider asking a new question, at this point this is Webpack problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help @estus I did manage to get the plugin working, what's odd in my mind is that some circular references don't seem to cause the issue but some do. It feels like a pure timing issue / race condition kind of thing which doesn't sit too well with me,
I've managed to remove some of the references but some are unavoidable without a lot of file splitting. I will repost this as a webpack question.

Comment: If you access CD right after import, there's race condition, otherwise there isn't. That you don't know if you can access it or not safely until the problem occurs is the actual reason why CDs are bad. The gist of your case is `var key, obj = { key: key }; setTimeout(() => console.log(obj)); key = true`. Even though you don't need to access `key` value until timeout, you access it too early and it's undefined. That's what happens with ES modules when CDs are resolved.

Comment: Yeah, that's it, nail on the head. The unpredictable nature of it is my main problem. It's a bit frustrating as I pushed for the shorthand `mapDispatchToProps` notation and now will probably end up having to role it back. Which on a large project, having to put all the parameters back in, is a PITA!

Comment: And I guess actually that's why I feel the issue is part `webpack` part `redux`. Webpack's module resolution (and I guess any es6 module resolution) allows this situation to occur, so the way redux handles the imports (evaluating instantly and passing as params directly) on shorthand notation is part of the problem. 
It feels like the two don't place nicely together

Comment: @dougajmcdonald I don't think that Redux should be blamed, it's unopinionated and doesn't impose any restrictions on how modules are designed. That there's a CD means that some of your modules needs to be separated or so. As I said, `dispatch => ...` is just a workaround. It's good that it exists but this doesn't mean it has to be used.